# I cannot install any packages

Tags: apt

My new Ubuntu Dell laptop version 12.04 is not playing videos.

I get the error message,

```
mpeg-4 aac codec not installed
```

I can't install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package

Here is the error message:

```
-Vostro-3546:~# sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I get the same error when I try to install any package.

Answer (score 2):

1. Activate repositories from **Software & Updates**
2. Before any installation, run `sudo apt-get update`.